# Google Cloud Run Service not able to call Google Cloud Workflow's Callback Url without OAuth Token

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

1. I have developed an Asynchronous Google Cloud Run Service.
2. This service is triggered as part of Google Cloud Workflow.
3. This Google Cloud Run Service responds back immediately with Response Status Code 201 and proccesses request in the background.
4. Once the service is done with processing of the request, it has to call the callback url of the workflow to share the response. However now the service has to pass an OAuth Token to call the callback url of the workflow in order to share the response with the workflow. This requires the codebase to create a new oauth token. The new auth token is then sent as a part of the header.
5. Is there a way where we don't have to pass the oauth token in the callback's request url. Intent is to make the service **Cloud Provider Agnostic**.

[image]

**Workflow Code**

```yaml
main:
  params: [input]
  steps:
  - create_callback_url:
      call: events.create_callback_endpoint
      args:
        http_callback_method: POST
      result: callback_details
  - prepare_report:
      call: http.post
      args:
        url: <reporting_service_url>
        body:
          id: ${input.id}
          params: ${input.params}
          callback_url: ${callback_details.url}
          # Is there a way we can include an Authorization Header here
          # Such that the service need not generate a token
          callback_authorization_token: null
        auth:
          type: OIDC
  - await_report_generation_callback:
      call: events.await_callback
      args:
        callback: 
        timeout: 3600
      result: generated_report_results
  - return_output:
      return: ${generated_report_results}
```

**Service Code Snippet**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks, Request
import shortuuid

app = FastAPI()

def callback(callback_url, token, payload):
    bearer_token = token if token else get_token_from_service_account_credentials()
    requests.post(url=callback_url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"}, json=payload)

# Intent is to get away from this function. 
# Is there a way Cloud Workflow could pass the Authentication Token
def get_token_from_service_account_credentials():
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
    )
    google_auth_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    credentials.refresh(google_auth_request)
    return credentials.token

def generate_report(report_generation_request: ReportGenerationServiceRequest):
    # Logic to generate report
    # The logic above would populate the payload
    payload = {}
    callback(report_generation_request.callback_url, report_generation_request.callback_authorization_token, {})

class ReportGenerationServiceRequest(BaseModel):
    """
    Represents a Transcription Generation AI Request
    """
    id: Optional[str]
    audio_file_path: AnyHttpUrl
    callback_url: AnyHttpUrl
    callback_authorization_token: str

@app.post("/")
def generate_report_requests(report_generation_request: ReportGenerationServiceRequest, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(generate_report, report_generation_request)
    return {"id": shortuuid.uuid()}
```

Comment: How about using short-lived tokens?

Comment: I guess short lived tokens would still require cloud provider specific code, which I want to avoid in the code. Any other thoughts on this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#use_the_metadata_server) to fetch ID token, you can avoid the Google Client libraries.

Not sure it meets your requirement for Cloud Provider agnostics though.

Above lists some other methods of authentication, like Application Default Credentials (still uses Google Client Libraries though).